# MySQL trigger creation - missing semicolon

Tags: mysql

im new in SQL programming. I need to create a trigger which after delete on "czytelnik" will also delete all records from "wypożyczył" which have the same CzytelnikID.

My code:

```
create trigger zadanie10
after update on czytelnik
for each row begin

if(old.Nazwisko != new.Nazwisko) then
delete from wypożyczył
where CzytelnikID=old.CzytelnikID;
end if;

end;
```

I got no idea what is worng in this code. Getting error after
 "old.CzytelnikID;"
 "end if;"
 "end;"

I bypassed my problem this way:

```
create trigger zadanie10
after update on czytelnik
for each row

delete from wypożyczył
where old.CzytelnikID=wypożyczył.CzytelnikID and old.Nazwisko!=new.Nazwisko;
```

But if anybody know why i couldnt do the first way, please tell me.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: missing semicolon, 'end' is not valid input at this position, extraneous input found - expected end of input

Comment: Are you sure the semicolon is a semicolon, and not another character. Don't know about your character set, but I do know the Greek question mark looks like a semicolon, but is a different character.

Comment: yes i am sure 100%

Comment: I bypassed my problem this way:
    create trigger zadanie10
    after update on czytelnik
    for each row
    
    delete from wypożyczył
    where old.CzytelnikID=wypożyczył.CzytelnikID and      old.Nazwisko!=new.Nazwisko;